# can not access website via localhost but 127.0.0.1

Tags: apache, curl, localhost

I was using virtual box and have had httpd installed on it, the network was configured as 'nat' and I forward port 8080 of Host Machine to port 80 of Virtual Machine.
Then I tried to access the Website hosted on the virtual machine via `curl localhost:8080 -vv`, but I got `Empty reply from server`, instead if I use `curl 127.0.0.1:8080 -vv` then everything is ok, why would it be like this ?

Comment: Check what IP address localhost is mapped to by doing a ping localhost. Other than that check to ensure you haven't got a typo.

Comment: it's mapped to 127.0.0.1

Comment: Did you get an empty response or a timeout. If empty response then check whether you are using named based virtual hosts and the request is not going to the host you think it should be.

Comment: network between hosted machine and virtual machine is nat

Comment: Finally I got the anwser, the `ping` shows that `localhost` is mapped to 127.0.0.1, while the `curl -vv` shows that it is being mapped to a `IPV6` address, sorry didn't read the `curl` results carefully

Comment: Its good you got to the bottom of it.